# How to properly send 16 bit integers to GLSL Shaders via Buffer Texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, buffer

I have 3072 values of type `std::int16_t` (16 bit integer), which corresponds to a `GLshort`. I want to send those to my GLSL Shaders. I read up on [Buffer Textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) and tried to implement that approach. However, the data does not seem to be intact anymore once it arrives in the Shader. I'm not certain yet, but it looks like the values are all either `0` or maxed out. What am I doing wrong?

My initialization code looks like this (bar some stuff that isn't relevant):

```
// 1: Get the data - array of GLshort:

GLshort tboData[3072];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3072; ++i)
{
    // cdb.getSprite() returns std::int16_t
    tboData[i] = (GLshort) cbd.getSprite(i);
}

// 2: Make sure the Shader Program is being used:

sp->use(); // sp is a wrapper class for GL Shader Programs

// 3: Generate the GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, bind it and send the data:

GLuint tbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &tbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, sizeof(tboData), tboData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// 4: Generate the Buffer Texture, activate and bind it:

GLuint tboTex;
glGenTextures(1, &tboTex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); // GL_TEXTURE0 is a spritesheet
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tboTex);

// 5: Associate them using `GL_R16` to match the 16 bit integer array:

glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R16, tbo);

// 6: Make the connection within the Shader:

glUniform1i(sp->getUniformLocation("tbo"), 1);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);
```

At the beginning of my rendering loop, I make sure everything is bound:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteSheet);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tboTex);
```

In my rendering loop, I set a uniform that will be used to index the TBO:

```
glUniform1i(sp->getUniformLocation("tboIndex"), tboIndex);
```

Now, the **Vertex Shader's** important pieces:

```
#version 140

// other ins, outs, uniforms ...

uniform int tboIndex;
uniform isamplerBuffer tbo;
out float pass_Sprite; // Frag shader crashes when this is int, why?

void main()
{
    // gl_Position, matrices, etc ...
    pass_Sprite = texelFetch(tbo, tboIndex).r;
}
```

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> GL_R16

That is an unsigned *[normalized integer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Normalized_Integer)* format. Your buffer sampler expects signed, *non-normalized* integers.

The [correct image format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) would be `GL_R16I`.

> Frag shader crashes when this is int, why

Probably because you didn't use [`flat` interpolation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers). Interpolation doesn't work for non-floating-point values.

And it wouldn't crash; it would simply fail to compile. You should *always* check compile errors in your shaders.

Comment: First, you are amazing. Second, it all makes sense now! On the linked wiki page, I thought that the "NORM" column within the table of image formats would tell us whether an image format *has* to be supported by the driver/hardware. Now I understand it means *normalized*. Also, I completely missed the `u` in `ushort`, stupid me. Also, you are right about the shader "crash", that was just a simplification. It does, in fact, just not compile. I'm going to look into flat interpolation, the page you linked does, however, not contain any information. At any rate, thank you so much!